# com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

My Build failed, This was the error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
    > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
    > The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.1,16.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

Below is the root Gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the app Gradle file.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.yourcompany.login"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Of what I think this a compatibility issue and I got no success searching the same errors on different forums.
P.S: I am a newbie, so spare me on the downvotes if you find that my question is not framed properly.